# Gson and Double

Tags: android, gson, spring-data-jpa, retrofit

I'm writing a mobile application in Android. I have a TomCat server, use SpringBoot and SpringData JPA. To connect Android to the server, I use Retrofit. I'm pretty much a rookie at it so I don't know all the stuff. Could you help me please? I need help with transferring data from Android and saving them into database which is on the server. I have a field/space in Double database. And after transferring the data from Android, I am getting nulls in the places where I should've had doubles. Could you help me out please?
Below, I'm putting the code from the base and the one from Android.

From Android:
ApiClient:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.129:8080/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
                .create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Xero:

```
public class Xero {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
Long id;
@SerializedName("name_xero")
@Expose
String name_xero;
@SerializedName("street_xero")
@Expose
String street_xero;
@SerializedName("number_building_xero")
@Expose
String number_building_xero;
@SerializedName("A1")
@Expose
 String A1;
@SerializedName("A2")
@Expose
 String A2;
@SerializedName("A3")
@Expose
 String A3;
@SerializedName("A4")
@Expose
String A4;

public Xero(String name_xero, String street_xero, String 
number_building_xero,String  A1, String  A2, String  A3, String  A4) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name_xero = name_xero;
    this.street_xero = street_xero;
    this.number_building_xero = number_building_xero;
    this.A1 = A1;
    this.A2 = A2;
    this.A3 = A3;
    this.A4 = A4;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName_xero() {
    return name_xero;
}

public void setName_xero(String name_xero) {
    this.name_xero = name_xero;
}

public String getStreet_xero() {
    return street_xero;
}

public void setStreet_xero(String street_xero) {
    this.street_xero = street_xero;
}

public String getNumber_building_xero() {
    return number_building_xero;
}

public void setNumber_building_xero(String number_building_xero) {
    this.number_building_xero = number_building_xero;
}
public String  getA1() {
    return A1;
}

public void setA1(String  A1) {
    this.A1 = A1;
}

public String  getA2() {
    return A2;
}

public void setA2(String  A2) {
    this.A2 = A2;
}
public String  getA3() {
    return A3;
}

public void setA3(String  A3) {
    this.A3 = A3;
}

public String  getA4() {
    return A4;
}

public void setA4(String  A4) {
    this.A4 = A4;
}
}
```

XeroFragment:

```
public class XeroFragment extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.nameXeroEditText)
EditText nameXeroEditText;
@BindView(R.id.streetXeroEditText)
EditText streetXeroEditText;
@BindView(R.id.numberbuildingEditText)
EditText numberbuildingEditText;
@BindView(R.id.A1priceeditText)
EditText A1priceeditText;
@BindView(R.id.A2priceeditText)
EditText A2priceeditText;
@BindView(R.id.A3priceeditText)
EditText A3priceeditText;
@BindView(R.id.A4priceeditText)
EditText A4priceeditText;
@BindView(R.id.addButton)
Button addButton;
Unbinder unbinder2;

public XeroFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Hierarchia widoków za pomocą inflate id układu i pojemnik
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_xero, container, 
   false);//na podstawie inflate i layout utworzony widok
    // setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    unbinder2 = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
@Override

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}


public class OnFragmentInteractionListener {
}

@OnClick(R.id.addButton)
public void onButtonClicked() {
    Xero xero = new Xero(
            nameXeroEditText.getText().toString(),
            streetXeroEditText.getText().toString(),
            numberbuildingEditText.getText().toString(),
          A1priceeditText.getText().toString(),
          A2priceeditText.getText().toString(),
          A3priceeditText.getText().toString(),
          A4priceeditText.getText().toString()
    );
    sendNetworkRequestXero(xero);
}

 private void sendNetworkRequestXero(Xero xero) {



    //create retrofit instance
      AddXeroClient addXeroClient = 
ApiClient.getClient().create(AddXeroClient.class);
      Call<Xero> call = addXeroClient.create(xero);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Xero>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Xero> call, Response<Xero> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"OnResponse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
MenuVisitorActivity.class);
            XeroFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("Xero", "onResponse: " + statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Xero> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Xero", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Xero from SpringData JPA:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name= "xero")
public class Xero {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id_xero", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL")
private String name_xero;
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
private String street_xero;
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL")
private String number_building_xero;
@Column
private Double A1;
@Column
private Double A2;
@Column
private Double A3;
@Column
private Double A4;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "visitor_id")
private Visitor visitor;

public Xero() {
}

public Xero(String name_xero, String street_xero, String 
number_building_xero, Double a1, Double a2, Double a3, Double a4) {
    this.name_xero = name_xero;
    this.street_xero = street_xero;
    this.number_building_xero = number_building_xero;
    this.A1 = a1;
    this.A2 = a2;
    this.A3 = a3;
    this.A4 = a4;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName_xero() {
    return name_xero;
}

public void setName_xero(String name_xero) {
    this.name_xero = name_xero;
}

public String getStreet_xero() {
    return street_xero;
}

public void setStreet_xero(String street_xero) {
    this.street_xero = street_xero;
}

public String getNumber_building_xero() {
    return number_building_xero;
}

public void setNumber_building_xero(String number_building_xero) {
    this.number_building_xero = number_building_xero;
}

public Double getA1() {
    return A1;
}

public void setA1(Double a1) {
    A1 = a1;
}

public Double getA2() {
    return A2;
}

public void setA2(Double a2) {
    A2 = a2;
}

public Double getA3() {
    return A3;
}

public void setA3(Double a3) {
    A3 = a3;
}

public Double  getA4() {
    return A4;
}

public void setA4(Double a4) {
    A4 = a4;
}


public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public Visitor getVisitor() {
    return visitor;
}

public void setVisitor(Visitor visitor) {
    this.visitor = visitor;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Xero[ id=" + id +
            ", name_xero=" + name_xero +
            ", street_xero=" + street_xero +
            ", number_building_xero=" + number_building_xero +
            ", A1=" + A1 +
            ", A2=" + A2 +
            ", A3=" + A3 +
            ", A4=" + A4+ "]";
   }
 }
```

XeroController from SpringData JPA:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/xero")
public class XeroController  {
private XeroRepository xeroRepository;

@Autowired
public XeroController(XeroRepository xeroRepository) {
    this.xeroRepository=xeroRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addXero(@RequestBody Xero xero)
{
    xeroRepository.save(xero);
    return "{success:true}";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Xero> getXero(){
    return xeroRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Comment: post your json Response